# Join every 3 lines together Python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I currently have a list stored in a variable for example:

- 01/01/2015
- 13:22
- Steak
- 01/02/2015
- 13:23
- Fries
- 01/03/2015
- 13:23
- Salad

I have a variable z that holds this information.

I want to join every 3 lines together so the output is date + time + order in one line. I tried the below but this puts 3 letters on each line rather than the 3 lines

```
threelines = range(0,len(z),3)
for num, line in enumerate(z):
    if num in threelines:
        print ' '.join(z[num:num+3])
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: What is `z`?...

Comment: It would help if you include some actual input (say, the first 9 values of z?) and expected output (say, the three lines with the formatting you want) to the question.

Comment: Are you looking for [How do you split a list into evenly sized chunks in Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/312443/953482)?

Comment: @BhargavRao: From the symptoms, I'd say that `z` is a string. But it would be good if SB77 could confirm that, preferably by adding some example data to the question. Otherwise, the question's in grave danger of being closed as unclear.

Comment: Hi Sorry I will update my question

Comment: @SB77: Your update hasn't clarified the exact form of `z`. My guess is that your data is in a single string, with individual items separated by newlines, or perhaps by commas or some other separator character. Or it could be in a Python list of strings, but if that were the case your current code would do what you want (albeit in a rather strange way), as the answers below indicate. So to clarify this issue you should add code showing us what `z` _really_ looks like, similar to how all the answers have done.

Answer (score 3):

You do not need to use an index, and you can write very explicit code like:

```
lines_iter = iter(z.splitlines())  # If z is a file, lines_iter = z works
# itertools.izip() is usable, too, for a low memory footprint:
for date_time_order in zip(lines_iter, lines_iter, lines_iter):
    print " ".join(date_time_order)  # "<date> <time> <order>"
```

This has the advantage of giving you very legible variable names, and also of working even if `z` is an iterator (like a file): there is no need to know the number of lines in advance, and this method uses little memory.

The way it works comes from the specifics of how `zip()` works: [it builds tuples of elements, by getting the next element of each of its arguments in turn](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip). Thus, it first returns the first, second, and third element of `lines_iter`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I dont know where you get z from but from your description it look like this:

```
# define z ......
z = ['date1', 'time1', 'Order1','date2', 'time2', 'Order2','date3', 'time3', 'Order3','date4', 'time4', 'Order4',]
# if z is a string with newlines (you mentioned lines...)
string_with_newlines ="date1\ntime1\nOrder1\ndate2\ntime2\nOrder2"
z = string_with_newlines.splitlines()
# z becomes ['date1', 'time1', 'Order1','date2', 'time2', 'Order2'] and that is a real list^

# make new list
l = []

# iterate over 3 items in z
for n in range(len(z)//3):
    # join the 3 item from z for this iteration and put them into the new list
    l.append(' '.join(z[n*3:n*3+3]))

print l

# print output
['date1 time1 Order1',
 'date2 time2 Order2',
 'date3 time3 Order3',
 'date4 time4 Order4']
```

Comment: I doubt that `z` is a list of strings. If it was, OP's original code would already be working.

Comment: @Kevin mhh. ill add splitlines ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Your code already works, but only if `z` is a list of strings, rather than a single string.

Original:

```
z = """Hello,
how
are
you?
I
am
fine.
Lovely
Weather."""

threelines = range(0,len(z),3)
for num, line in enumerate(z):
    if num in threelines:
        print ' '.join(z[num:num+3])
```

Result:

```
H e l
l o ,

 h o
...
```

Using a list instead:

```
z = """Hello,
how
are
you?
I
am
fine.
Lovely
Weather."""

z = z.split("\n")

threelines = range(0,len(z),3)
for num, line in enumerate(z):
    if num in threelines:
        print ' '.join(z[num:num+3])
```

Result:

```
Hello, how are
you? I am
fine. Lovely Weather.
```

---

Incidentally, your `num in threelines` check is a little inefficient for large inputs. I suggest using the chunking recipe from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/312443/how-do-you-split-a-list-into-evenly-sized-chunks-in-python) post instead.

```
z = """Hello,
how
are
you?
I
am
fine.
Lovely
Weather."""

z = z.split("\n")

def chunks(l, n):
    """ Yield successive n-sized chunks from l.
    """
    for i in xrange(0, len(l), n):
        yield l[i:i+n]

for chunk in chunks(z, 3):
    print " ".join(chunk)
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually, if `z` is a list of strings like

```
z = ['first line', 'second line', 'third line', ...]
```

your code should work. (and if it's not but it's a simple string you can make it a list of lines by using `z.splitlines()` or `z.split()` if they are separeted by spaces)

But it's particularly wasteful: you generate a list with all the indices that are multiple of 3, then enumerate the elements of your lists and if the index is in the list of indices multiple of 3 (a check you perform at every iteration!), you print the current element and the two after it.

You can directly generate chunks of 3 consecutive elements without using a condition inside a for loop. You can find multiple solutions here: [How do you split a list into evenly sized chunks?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/312443/how-do-you-split-a-list-into-evenly-sized-chunks-in-python)

A simple one is:

```
z[i:i+3] for i in xrange(0, len(z), 3)
```